# Object array java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I would like to create an object array but I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. At the moment I don't know why and can't find the mistake. The class will be saved in the GAE datastore. It would be nice if anyone could tell me what went wrong.

What I did:

```
@Transient private int plc = 0;
@Transient private Profile[] players = new Profile[4];

public void setPlayers(Profile player) {
    if (plc < 4) {
        this.players[plc] = new Profile(); // Exception
        this.players[plc] = player;
        plc++;
    }
}
```

What do I miss?

**Profile constructor**

```
public Profile() {
}

public Profile(String account, String name, int gender) {
    this.account = account;
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}
```

**Stracktrace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at packgesname.Game.setPlayers(Game.java:40)
    at packgesname.JsonServlet.joinParty(JsonServlet.java:115)
    at packgesname.JsonServlet.doGet(JsonServlet.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:110)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: Where do you get your exception ?

Comment: Presumably, `players` is null.

Comment: Your *first* assignment to `this.players[plc]` is useless, since you overwrite it with the second one.

Comment: It's unclear as to what you're really doing, and where your NPE is

Comment: I suspect you stripped your code too much for the question. The error isn't probably in what we see.

Comment: in some part of the code that you're not showing, you're setting players to null

Comment: I added a comment at the line. @joachim-sauer ye, i added this line just for testing, to be sure, that the line after that is not the problem.

Comment: show the stack trace in your console

Comment: I think what others have said is correct, this.players must be null, are you sure youre not setting it elsewhere? We might need to see more code...

Comment: I checked it, if i arrive the function `setPlayers`, the var `players` is definitely `null`.

Comment: YOu could try pasting the whole class if its not too big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've marked `players` with the `@Transient` annotation. I don't know what library this one is from, but it probably isn't setting it to a value since it probably isn't calling the constructor (thus initializing it there) nor is it setting the value (because it's transient). Try lazily initializing it like so:

```
public void setPlayers(Profile player) {
    if (this.players == null)
        this.players = new Profile[4];
    if (plc < 4) {
        this.players[plc] = new Profile(); // Exception
        this.players[plc] = player;
        plc++;
    }
}
```

Remember that serialization libraries will not serialize transient values in any way, and the new objects will have `null` for transient fields, even if you initialize them in the constructor. This is because for most serialization libraries, the object is *allocated*, not *constructed*, by the library, and then its values are set after allocation. This skips over your constructor and doesn't initialize the transient `players` to anything, leaving it `null`.

If you want to be sure, put a breakpoint in the constructor and serialize your object, then deserialize it. If the deserialization is calling the constructor (i.e. via reflection or some similar mechanism), then it will hit your breakpoint. If it doesn't, then this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem within your `Profile`constructor, is there some code that could throw a `NullPointerException` there ?

Comment: Nice idea, let me have a look!

Comment: I added the stacktrace. I can't find a problem in `Profile`. I will add the constructor too.